# Any software on windows that can completely block internet access?

Tags: windows, internet

Not to block a website, not to block social websites like Twitter or Facebook, but to block the *whole* internet. And while the program is running, you can do nothing about it. It's a self-control program.

Is there any software on Windows that can block the whole internet?

---

**Edit**: No longer *free* requirement.

Comment: do you need local area network access or should this be disabled too?

Comment: @SeanCheshire That does not matter too much...Frankly, I haven't think about this. But that's a very nice question.

Comment: @AveMaleficum if you don't care about network connection, just disable the ethernet adapter that is used for internet connection.

Comment: @Cornelius I don't get it, and what should I do to disable the ethernet adapter?

Comment: @Cornelius And I can easily chose able, right?

Comment: @Cornelius That's not what I want, check my updated question above.

Comment: Trying to focus on your work instead of wandering around YouTube/FB/etc? :)

Comment: So when the program is **quit**, you want to be able to access the internet? BUT... you shouldn't be able to access the internet at all if the program is **open**?

Comment: I think the short version here is, I start the program and no matter what I do, the internet is disabled for lets say 4 hours, then it pops back on.  The best answer here is teach yourself discipline (it aint easy) but yeah anyway I think that is what is being asked.

Answer (score 4):

You would need Web Filtering software. The first one I found was http://www1.k9webprotection.com/ which has time restrictions, and is free to home users (get a licence key from their [Get K9 Now](http://www1.k9webprotection.com/get-k9-web-protection-free) page. If you want to search for other free programs, then searching for `free web filter -trial` should get you more choices.

---

Retaining below instructions for other users reference

---

To restrict all access, disable the network adapter.

(screenshots from Windows 7)
[image: Properties of network adapter]

If you want to allow the LAN, but not the internet, go to the propertied, fill in the IP address and Mask, and remove the Gateway:
[image]

If you don't know what the IP address and Mask are, open up a command prompt ( <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, then enter `cmd`), and type `ipconfig`

you will get something that looks like this:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\windows\system32>ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration


Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fc80::c007:ab08:643f:b7a%10
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.104
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
```

Comment: No, that't not what I mean, I am sorry, maybe my question is not clear, what I want is a software that can disable the internet and you can do nothing about it. It's a self-control program. I am not asking how to disable the internet.

Comment: @AveMaleficum, see update

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for an app like Toggle Your Internet or Let Me Work or Internet Off by CrystalRich? There seem to be a lot of 'roll your own' type scripts and such out there for Windows systems as well - these essentially carry out the steps that @SeanC has laid out in his post above.

Comment: Links would improve this answer.

Comment: @Menasheh - you are correct, thank you for the comment. If I remember correctly as a new user I was not able to include links in my post. Also, some of the potential links for these kinds of tools were of dubious quality and/or integrity.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use Blacklist or Whitelist settings in Firewall to control internet access of applications.

App name: Firewall App Blocker, tiny & easy to use app (just drag & drop the applications).

https://www.sordum.org/8125/firewall-app-blocker-fab-v1-7/

To block individual sites, you can modify hosts file, add the domain you wish to block and map ip address to 127.0.0.1 or 0.0.0.0

If you find this answer useful please upvote it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome to our community Subhash!  Please add clarity to your answer as well as an official link to the software you are recommending.  Thanks, and again, welcome!